# Any automated way to unit test Flash Clipboard functionality from the browser in Flash Player 10+

Tags: flash, browser, actionscript, automated-tests, zeroclipboard

In Flash Player 10+, a browser-based SWF can inject into a user's clipboard *if and only if* it is triggered by a user interaction with the Flash object, e.g. the user clicks a Flash button. This is done using the `flash.desktop.Clipboard.generalClipboard` object's `clear` and `setData` methods.

I've used this trick for many web apps (e.g. via [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) and similar previous implementations of my own) but now I would like to put some automated testing around it if at all possible. Is there any way to do this?

I've looked through a few but didn't spot any that were **proven** to work for this very specific purpose (from any related documentation, blogs, etc. that I can find):

- FlashSelenium just relies on `ExternalInterface` callbacks, which don't count as user interactions.
- FlexUnit seems to be non-browser-based.
- Adobe Genie may or may not work, I honestly couldn't find enough useful documentation to tell.
- PhantomJS 1.4.x (and earlier) supported Flash and *can* send "authentic" user events, so this seemed like it might be the best option. However, I don't relish using a version of PhantomJS that is 5 minor versions behind (more than 1 year old). Has anyone used PhantomJS to automate Flash interactions that can confirm it works and offer some advice?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at something like FlexMonkey by GorillaLogic?  It allows you to do automated functional testing by recording your interaction with the app.  It is discontinued but they still have the download link on their site.

They have a new product, MonkeyTalk, but at the moment it only supports mobile projects (even though some of their documentation says it supports web and desktop projects, it currently does not)

Comment: I looked at it briefly. It seemed like it might be a viable option but the Clipboard API in particular requires elevated permissions that can only be gained by legitimate user interactions in the browser -- i.e a click or keyboard event.  I do not believe that FlexMonkey could replay those events as authentic user events in the browser but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Do you have any FlexMonkey experience that would suggest otherwise?

Comment: Ive actually never gotten FlexMonkey to work properly in my project.  I get compile errors when I include the library (Adobe Automation API classes couldnt be found) but thought you might have more luck than me.  There are some other products out there that do the same thing, but I suspect you will still have the Clipboard permissions problem.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for offering up the suggestion anyway. :)